# how to join a certain string values in a list

Tags: python

I got a list

```
my_lst = ["a", "b", "c","d","e","f","g"]
```

and I need it to be

```
my_lst = ["a", "b", {"c","d","e","f","g"}]
```

in other words i need to concate all values from index 2 to the end in the form of {"",""} and drop all concated elements

Comment: What attempts have you made so far? Any code you can post?

Comment: FYI "the form of {"", ""}" is a `set`.

Comment: ive tried looping but invain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using unpacking:

```
[*my_lst[:2], set(my_lst[2:])]
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', {'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'}]
```

You can make the last element as a whole string with `str`:

```
[*my_lst[:2], str(set(my_lst[2:]))]
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', "{'f', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'g'}"]
```

Comment: but i dont need it a set , i need it to join inside that form u got me , not a set in a list as an example : [1 , 2 ,3 ,{"4","5","6"}]

Comment: @ashrafkhaled You mean as one whole string?

Comment: @ashrafkhaled Updated. Let me know if its desired.

Comment: can i maintain order?

Comment: @ashrafkhaled You say you want a string, but you keep giving examples like `[1 , 2 ,3 ,{"4","5","6"}]`. Here the last element is a `set`.

Comment: ok its a string and i want it like set as chris did but in the same order of list @Chris

Comment: @Chris This is actually a nice use of `str()`

Comment: buddy if its a list of lists of strings, any idea how can I do it? , strings in the form like ["a-daf","b-daf","c-daf"] and so on

Comment: @ashrafkhaled To keep the order, it isn't as simple. I would do `[*my_lst[:2], str(my_lst[2:]).replace("[", "{").replace("]","}")]`. For the last comment, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to move the rest into a set, and cut the list into the first 2 elements

```
my_lst, helper = my_lst[:2], my_lst[2:]
my_lst.append(set(helper))
```

Comment: `append` returns `None`.

Comment: Or without an additional helper variable: `my_lst = my_lst[:2] + [set(my_lst[2:])]`

Comment: much simpler : `my_lst  = my_lst[:2] + [set(my_lst[2:])]`

Comment: Code golf time :P

Comment: `['a', 'b', {'g', 'f', 'c', 'd', 'e'}]`

Comment: Playing code golf: `my_lst[2:]=[set(my_lst[2:])]`. Of course this modifies the existing list and doesn't create a new one.